# Can't change magento attribute frontend properties

Tags: magento-1.9, attributes, layered-navigation

I've added a custom attribute: `year` and have imported some products that use that attribute. I now want to change the `Used in Layer Navigation` from `Filterable` to `No`, but every time I save, it just pushes me to the attributes list page and the change isn't saved. Tried changing other fields - same issue. It's not a System attribute.

How do I fix this/get around it?

Comment: Have you cleared your magento cache ??? Please clear magento cache and try again

Comment: cache is off - but i don't see how that could relate to my question....

Comment: hi, do you want to use year in layered navigation to filter the resulys right?

Comment: I've set it as YES, but now I want to remove it from the Layered navigation. The issue is that no change I make to that attribute is saved - just remains the same whatever I try

Comment: Ok Sixli. 
Do one thing. Open year attribute in admin panel.
at frontend properties you have to make some changes.
i.e., Use in layerd navigation=Filterable with results.
And use in search results layered put Yes.

Comment: @TejabhagavanKollepara - I do that - click SAVE and it doesn't save, just redirects me to the Attributes list page... is there any reason why it would do this? and is there a way I can change this option in the DB directly?

Comment: Delete the attribute, recreate it and reimport the data.... You can also try exporting the data and see what it looks like.

Comment: It's a 6hr import - would rather hack the DB if possible? :)

Comment: have you reindex all in your magento admin panel ??

Comment: Data is STRING, type of attribute is Multiselect. Yes, reindexed all.

Comment: can you post scrrenshot your attribute page ??

Comment: Attributes page (last on list): http://grab.by/MOUC
Attribute screenshot: http://grab.by/MOUI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use a date attribute in layered navigation. Most likely there was a corruption or something that circumvented this check that allowed you to set `Use In Layered Navigation` to `YES`

The default for `Catalog Input Type for Store Owner` -> `Date` will automatically grey the `Use In Layered Navigation` to `NO`

Delete the attribute and reimport your data.

EDIT: You can disable the attribute directly from the database, do so at your own risk.

In your DB find the field `is_filterable_in_search` in table `catalog_eav_attribute` for your attribute.

set `is_filterable_in_search` to `0`for your attribute

Comment: It is not an actual date. The attribute contains text - the site is about car parts so it contains a year range for which that part is suitable ie. "2001-2013" in text format

Comment: updated answer but do so at your own risk

Comment: That worked - but I also had to set `is_filterable` field to `0` - thanks!